# getting error "got an unexpected keyword argument 'trend'" with the ARIMA model

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, arima

I'm not sure why I'm getting this error when trying to run the model when running it in colab. Everything looks correct to me.

```
import pandas as pd
import yfinance
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import statsmodels.api as sm
import numpy as np
tesla_frame = yfinance.Ticker("TSLA").history(start='2020-01-01', end='2022-01-01', interval='1d').reset_index()['Close'].to_frame()
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = [16, 8]
series = tesla_frame['Close']
ar_deg = 4
model = sm.tsa.AutoReg(series, lags=ar_deg, trend='n').fit()
prediction = model.predict()
tesla_frame['Prediction'] = prediction
error_sq = (series - prediction) ** 2
error_sq[error_sq.isna()] = 0
```

The above works but when I run the ARIMA part I get an error. Code:

```
garch_model = sm.tsa.ARIMA(error_sq, order=(4,0,3), trend ='c').fit()
```

Error:

**TypeError: **new**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'trend'**

Also:

```
  arch_model = sm.tsa.ARIMA(error_sq, order=(4,0,0), trend ='c').fit()
```

Error:

**TypeError: **new**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'trend'**

Any idea how to correct this error?

Comment: Really generic answer but might be your problem. Double check the version of the statsmodels library you are using. I see this happen a lot when people are say, using the newest docs for a library, but running against an older version. It's a good bet the "trend" argument was introduced in a version later than you are using.

Answer (score 0):

I looked up statsmodel's documentation, and I bet your problem is you were reading the docs for a newer version than you had installed.

0.10 did not have the argument "trend":

https://www.statsmodels.org/v0.10.0/generated/statsmodels.tsa.arima_model.ARIMA.html?highlight=arima#statsmodels.tsa.arima_model.ARIMA

It seems it was introduced in 0.11:

https://www.statsmodels.org/v0.11.0/generated/statsmodels.tsa.arima.model.ARIMA.html?highlight=arima#statsmodels.tsa.arima.model.ARIMA

I'd bet you were reading the docs for 0.11 plus but have 0.10 or older installed.

Comment: I used this at the start !pip install statsmodels==0.11 to install the correct package then check the package was installed with sm.__version__ The package I have installed was 0.11.0

Comment: @user2946746 You will need to get at least version 0.13.0 for this to work properly. You can just get the current version (0.13.2 as of this moment) with `!pip install -U statsmodels`.